# python how to get tag from xml in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I have an xml

and I check if it is existed like this:

```
s = os.path.isfile(xmlFile)
```

I am loading it like this:

```
from lxml import etree
self.doc=etree.parse(xmlFile)
```

#### my questoin

how to get tags from that `doc`? lets say i have tag called "domain" and tag called "player" existed in "root/team/hello/player"

Comment: Have you looked at the [lxml documentation](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)?

Comment: @TylerMacDonell yes i did, they start by telling me about `Element` i tried to follow them, but they didn't say where to load the xml. where to use the root in? i even tested their codes. there is no clear way to load the xml and begin coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lxml documentation says that `parse()` method returns an `ElementTree` object in lxml and then you can call `getroot()` on that to get the root `Element`. Isn't that the missing piece you were looking for? Will something like this work?

```
self.doc=etree.parse(xmlFile)
root = self.doc.getroot() # Element object root
```

I guess once you get the Element, you can call subElement/child etc. methods given in the tutorial.

```
child_team = etree.subElement(root, "team")
child_hello = etree.subElement(child_team, "hello")
child_player = etree.subElement(child_hello, "player")
```

Check out this link for details: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function